# Problem in getting enthusiast badge

Tags: support, login, timezone, activity-badges

From last 3 to 4 weeks I am deliberately trying to get enthusiast badge on Stack Overflow. To achieve it, I have set Stack Overflow as home page in all the browsers, at work and at home. And, it is almost impossible to never open any browser at work (week days 9 to 6) and at home (weekends normally late 2nd half of the day) in a day.

This technique is working fine except for Saturdays. For some reason (I suspect it is something related to timezone etc), it seems like, Stack Overflow is not logging my entry for Saturdays. This has happened for at least last two weeks.

Could this issue be related to difference between timezone? My timezone is **UTC/GMT +5 hours**.

Comment: If you have to complain about not getting the enthusiast badge, then you're not enough of an enthusiast to deserve it.

Comment: @TheEstablishment I am not specifically complaining about a stupid, harmless badge. I saw a genuine issue while trying to get one. Kindly try to understand the problem and answer it :)

Comment: I know most people will see this question negatively and I could have made a different story up and get upvotes and stuff. But, I think people should try to understand the actual issue :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you visit the site at around the same time each day and visit more than just the home page your visit should be logged. So I see two problems:

1. You are just visiting the home page. If you view a user profile page, a question or the review tab that should be enough to register a visit. You'll have to actually reload the page rather than just relying on the browser's initial load to count.
2. You are just missing the UTC day. If you are UTC+5 then the Stack Exchange "day" changes at 7pm local time. Therefore if on Friday you visit at 6:30pm that will count as a visit for Friday, but if you visit at 7:30pm on Saturday that will count as a visit for **Sunday** thus effectively missing out Saturday. Try to visit each day well away from 7pm.

Comment: The 2nd one is not a cool feature anyway :/

Comment: @Umer - On the other hand, it works both ways. If you visit from 6:45 to 7:15 it counts as **two** days.

Comment: @UmerHayat: Yes it is. Imagine what a chaos it would be if everything wasn't on UTC.